# How to query on shared ids tables on sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 4 tables/models that shares ids as primary keys, but for the example I will just show 2

```
User: {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    }
Person: {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
```

I am using shared ids, so the person primary key is the primary key of User, it doesn't have autoimcrement. So is there a way to make a join between those 2 tables? I've tried to do something like:

```
getAll(){
    return User.getAll({
        include: [{
            model:Person,
        }]
    })
}
```

But since there is no relation it doesn't work. What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use include without a relationship. You could use a raw query to retrieve the information like:

```
var queryString = 'select * from User u join Person p on u.id = p.id where u.id = :sharedId';

models.sequelize
    .query(queryString, {
      replacements: { shareId: id},
      type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      res.json(attendance);
    });
```

But then you would have to implement validations to make sure tables are filled up correclty.

However I would encourage you to implement relationships between your tables as It would be more maintainable. Something like this:

```
var User  = sequelize.define("User", {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, name: 'name' },
  ...
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      User.hasOne(models.Person);
    }
  }
});

var Person = sequelize.define("Person", {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, name: 'name' },
  ...
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Person.belogsTo(models.User);
    }
  }
});
```